# Contributions appearing twice in Civi, once in Authorize - why?

Tags: contributions, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, authorize.net

We're on Civi 4.6.3. We use Authorize for recurring debit/credit card contributions (though we are switching over to iATS for bank drafts, and if that works well, switching over to iATS for credit/debit card as well).

Recently we've seen two contribution records appear for the same transaction that only processes once in Authorize. These are all online contributions. The time lag is typically a day or so between the two Civi contribution records.

Anyone else see this happening and have an idea as to why?